# What is webBuilder in ConfigureWebHostBuilder function?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

here is the code of programs.cs in .Net 5 razor page, I understand lambda expression, its syntax like this: (parameter) => {statement} and we have to pass the parameter to it , but I didn't understand how the webBuilder parameter get passed to ConfugureWebHostDefaults function?

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"we have to pass the parameter to it" - that's where you went wrong. *something* has to pass it a parameter when it's called, that something doesn't have to be *you*.

In this case, you're passing a lambda to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`. At some point, that method will construct (directly or indirectly, the details don't matter to us as callers) an `IWebHostBuilder`. At some point after that, the method will invoke the lambda and pass the `webBuilder` to it.

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigureWebHostDefaults` accepts the callback (`Action<IWebHostBuilder>`) with the interface of `IWebHostBuilder` which initializes the `WebHostBuilder` and it has `UseStartup` method which identifies the application startup class

ref:

1. ConfigureWebHostDefaults => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostbuilderextensions.configurewebhostdefaults?view=aspnetcore-5.0#parameters
2. IWebHostBuilder => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0